# Angular http client - get correct error code

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I working with `Angular 10.1.3`.

I have a service with

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
...
getDocument(id: string): Observable<any> {
 const fullUrl = this.apiUrl + 'documents/' + id;
 return this.http.get(fullUrl);
}
```

In my component I have something like

```
 this.myServive.getDocument(myValue).subscribe(
    response =>  { console.log(response); }, error => { console.log(error); }
  );
```

Let's say the api is down.  In the console I can see

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost.../documents/123", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost.../documents/123: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost..../documents/123"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

It the result of the `Console.log(error)`

The problem is that the only information I get is `Unknown Error`  I expanded all elements but nothing more interesting.

But in the console, just after, there is also

```
GET http://localhost.../documents/123 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It is not coming from the `Console.log(error)` so where is it coming from ?  How can I retrieve the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the component ?